# Permissions to avoid accidental deletion of a git repository

Tags: git, permissions

We have some git repositories on a file system path. The permission on all these repositories is 755.

The repositories have been shared using:

git init --shared=0775

This needs to be done because the repositories are shared with multiple users who are part of the same unix group.

Users clone the repositories using the file system path:

git clone /path/to/git/repository

The big potential risk with this approach is that, any user will be able to delete the entire .git folder from the repository itself.

How can this risk be mitigated?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas:

- Good old fashioned backups of the file system
- Regularly push to a remote repository on a different machine
- Simply rely on safety in numbers - if the central repository is deleted, it is highly likely that all essential information is already stored on one or several of the user repositories so a central repository can be reconstructed from them.